# How to delete a chart using google script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I wrote a script to automatically generate charts from data on different tabs (after clicking a button on a new sheet).

I would now like to add a "reset" button which will automatically delete or remove the generated charts (so I can generate different charts with another button).

Can anyone help on how I can do this? I've tried the below, but to no avail....

```
function Finance_clear() {

  function deleteAllChartsFromSheet(sheetName) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var chartsSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName); 
  var n = chartsSheet.getCharts().length;
  for (var i = n-1; i >= 0; i--) {  
    var chart = chartsSheet.getCharts()[i];
    chartsSheet.removeChart(chart);
  }
}
};
```

Answer (score 2):

## Delete All Charts from a Sheet

```
function delAllChartsFromSheet(name) {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName(name);
  var chts=sh.getCharts();
  for(var i=0;i<chts.length;i++){
    sh.removeChart(chts[i]);
  }
}
```

[Sheet Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet)

Comment: This isn't working. Should my spreadsheet name go where you have "(name)"? Should it just be entered with a single quote around it?

Comment: name is the sheet name.

Comment: This worked:
        function clear() {
  
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

    // This removes all the embedded charts from the spreadsheet
    var charts = sheet.getCharts();
    for (var i in charts) {
      sheet.removeChart(charts[i]);
    }
      }
        ;

The sheet that you want the charts to be removed/deleted will need to be the first sheet (tab) in your spreadsheet

Answer (score 0):

The code worked for me, I rewrote it as:

```
function remove_charts_from_sheet(sheet_name) {
  const tab = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sheet_name);
  const charts = tab.getCharts();
  for(let i = 0; i < charts.length; i++){
    tab.removeChart(charts[i]);
  }
}
```